# Recursive check for user in an AD Group

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, active-directory-group

I am trying to write a web service in C# that takes a username and AD group name, and returns true or false as a result.  Right now I'm doing something to the effect of this.

```
public static Boolean CheckGroupForUser(String username, String groupname) {

        Boolean Success = false;

        try
        {
            using (PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, username))
            using (GroupPrincipal gp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, groupname))
            {
                Success = user.IsMemberOf(gp);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Success = false;
        }
        return Success;
    }
```

This works fine.  Returns true if the user is in the group, returns false if they are not.  The problem is this.

Lets say I have an AD Group called TestGroup.  TestGroup has 1 user named Bob in it.

```
CheckGroupForUser("Bob","TestGroup"); //true
```

Lets say user Bob is also in the AD Group OtherGroup.  So I take Bob out of TestGroup, but add OtherGroup to TestGroup.  So now technically Bob is in TestGroup, but not directly.

```
CheckGroupForUser("Bob","TestGroup"); //false
```

This is where I need help.  I need this scenario to be true.  Catch my drift?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `System.DirectoryServices` you can do this [by using the rule LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN in your search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx).

Basically you use a filter like:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=userDN)
```

where userDN is the distinguished name of the user you're interested in.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but in this instance does '1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941' represent some unique identifier like an employee number or something?

EDIT:  I read the link you provided and realized this is an OID